# Vale a pela desenvolver em JavaFX para Web, Mobile e Desktop?

Tags: java, java-ee, mobile, javafx, aplicação-desktop

Gostaria de saber como que vai o JavaFX, se já se consolidou, se ainda é aposta..
Gostei muito do visual e do *"Write once, run everywhere"*.

Comment: "Tudo vale a pena / Se a alma não é pequena." - Fernando Pessoa.

Comment: Num tom mais sério, eu vejo poucas vagas para JavaFX no mercado. porém isso é apenas uma observação pessoal.

Comment: "Gostaria de saber como que vai o JavaFX" Vai mal, muito mal..

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de respostas eu ouço apenas grilos cantando. Me parece sinal de que não está consolidado não.

Tampouco pode ser aposta pois já é bem antigo.

## Interface web

As empresas que decidem o rumo da interface web decidiram que ele é HTML; mais precisamente HTML5.

Quem ousou desafiar tentando forçar a barra com interfaces que rodam no navegador mas na verdade renderizam as telas utilizando código compilado (Silverlight, Flex, o famigerado Flash e o próprio Java FX) teve suas ferramentas classificadas como cidadãos de segunda categoria e estão cada vez mais em desuso e menos populares.

## Write once run everywhere - plataformas mobile

HTML5 também tem sido bastante utilizado com o objetivo de *"write once run everywhere"* nas plataformas mobile, através de ferramentas como *PhoneGap* e *Intel's App Framework*.

Também há empresas que criam o próprio *container* para rodar aplicativos HTML5 em diferentes dispositivos.

Este método pode até não ser o melhor para se ter o melhor aplicativo Android ou o melhor aplicativo iOS, mas é provável que seja o de mais baixo custo e o mais rápido para lançar cedo um produto e aprimorá-lo mais tarde utilizando as ferramentas específicas de cada plataforma.

## Write once run everywhere - multiplataformas (mobile, desktop, web)

A técnica mais usada para isso atualmente são páginas web "normais"; eventualmente mas não necessariamente com layout responsivo (o layout se ajusta conforme o dispositivo utilizado para visualizar a página).

Dependendo do aplicativo que você vai fazer e do público alvo, isso pode servir muito bem.

Neste caso, do lado do servidor você usa a plataforma que bem entender. E, se o design do seu sistema for acertado desde o começo, você expande o sistema para rodar em outros dispositivos precisando apenas escrever novas interfaces conforme a plataforma - o código *back end* permanece o mesmo.